# How can i insert values into same table using gridview ? Asp.net c# ,sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try alot but i Can't find the solution of this problem.Here is my problem.Actually,I'm creating "DATABASE EDITOR" in ASP.NET C#.Here is my database "tbl_field" table [image]

in which user insert values and create table.I know this can be done be query easily,I can do it,but first i want to store values in table.I want that when user click on create table then every time this gridview open,here is image [image],When user click on "Insert" then values insert into database table "tbl_field" and also show inserted row above.But problem is when another user login then create table then this griview and inserted rows again show.I'm beginner,i don't know how can i handle this problem.I'm trying to explain my question,hopefully my question is clear.Here is my aspx code :`

```
<label id="welcome" style="color: Blue" runat="server">
</label>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="user" runat="Server">
<label style="position:relative; top:60px; left:140px  runat="server">Table Name </label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txttable" runat="server" style="position:relative;   top:60px; left:140px; border-style:double;" ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"  runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"  
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84"
    BorderColor="#DEBA84"  BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"
     ShowFooter="True" Style="margin-left: 136px; margin-top: 72px;
    margin-right: 0px;" Height="16px" Width="685px" onselectedindexchanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged" >

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Column_Name" SortExpression="Column_Name">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Column_Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator Text="*" ID="colname" ControlToValidate="txtName"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Column Name is Required" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Column_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="textColname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*" ID="insertcolname" ControlToValidate="textColname"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Column Name is Required" ForeColor="Red">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>


           </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Data_Type" SortExpression="Data_Type">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("Data_Type") %>'>
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Datatype</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Float</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(50)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(100)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>double</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="datatype" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Data Type is Required" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Datatype">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Data_Type") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Select Datatype</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>int</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Float</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(50)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Varchar(100)</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>double</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="INSERT" Text="*"  ID="datatype" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2"
                    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Data Type is Required" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="Select Datatype">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allow_Null_" SortExpression="Allow_Null_">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_")) %>'/>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Allow_Null_"))%>' enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="nulll" runat="server" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Primary_Key_" SortExpression="Primary_Key_">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Primary_Key_")) %>' />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" 
                                        Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Primary_Key_")) %>' Enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="primary" runat="server" />
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Insert">
        <FooterTemplate>


             <asp:LinkButton ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lbinssert">INSERT</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
</asp:GridView>

<asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="INSERT" ID="ValidationSummary1" ForeColor="Red"
    runat="server" Height="25px" style="margin-left: 140px" />
    <br />
<input type="submit" style="position:relative; width:30px; left:452px; top: 0px; width: 86px;" 
     value="Create table" name="create"/>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary2" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" 
    style="margin-left: 142px" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sql" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db_compilerConnectionString %>" 

     SelectCommand="SELECT [Table_Name], [Column_Name], [Data_Type], [Allow_Null_], [Primary_Key_], [Date] FROM [tbl_field]"
     DeleteCommand="DELETE  FROM [tbl_field] WHERE [Field_id]=@field" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_field] ([Table_Name],[Column_Name],[Data_Type],[Database_id],[Allow_Null_],[Primary_Key_])Values (@TableName,@ColumnName,@Dtype,@id,@null,@primary)"
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_field] SET [Table_Name]=@TableName, [Column_Name]=@ColumnName,[Data_Type]=@Dtype,[Database_id]=@id,[Allow_Null_]=@null,[Primary_Key_]=@primary">
     <DeleteParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="field" Type="Int32" />
     </DeleteParameters>
     <InsertParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="TableName" Type="String" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="ColumnName" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="Dtype" Type="String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="null" Type="Boolean" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="primary" Type="Boolean" />


     </InsertParameters>
     <UpdateParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="TableName" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="ColumnName" Type="String" />
      <asp:Parameter Name="Dtype" Type="String" />
       <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="null" Type="Boolean"/>
         <asp:Parameter Name="primary" Type="Boolean" />

     </UpdateParameters>

 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and here is aspx.cs code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMEED_KHAN\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_compiler;Integrated Security=True");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl_field", cnn);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(dt);
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;

        FixGridFooter(dt);
}
 public void lbinssert(Object sender,EventArgs e)
{

    sql.InsertParameters["TableName"].DefaultValue = txttable.Text;


    sql.InsertParameters["ColumnName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("textColname")).Text;

      sql.InsertParameters["Dtype"].DefaultValue = ((DropDownList)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownList2")).Text;

    sql.InsertParameters["id"].DefaultValue = Session["value"].ToString();

    sql.InsertParameters["null"].DefaultValue =
      ((CheckBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("nulll")).Checked == true ? "true" : "false";
    sql.InsertParameters["primary"].DefaultValue = ((CheckBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("primary")).Checked == true ? "true" : "false";

    sql.Insert();
 }
public void FixGridFooter(DataTable dataSour)
{


    dataSour.Rows.Add(dataSour.NewRow());
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Table_Name"] = 0;
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Column_Name"] = 0;
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Data_Type"] = "";
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Database_id"] = 0;
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Allow_Null_"] = true;
    dataSour.Rows[0]["Primary_Key_"] = false;
   dataSour.Rows[0]["Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
   GridView2.DataSource = dataSour;
    GridView2.DataBind();

    //hide empty row - if you want to display it on an event like a button click else it will display as per default.
    GridView2.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    GridView2.ShowFooter = true;
}
```

Actually,I bound the values in the database table so every time table show inserted values etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your problem is that you want to display only headers initially, when no data is inserted, then you can try to use `GridView` Property `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`. This property  indicates whether the heading of a column in the GridView control is visible when the column has no data.
2. In case you need to show an empty row along with header when no data is present in gridview, then you need to bind the `gridview` with List containing one dummy element, which can be initialized when no data is coming from database.

Comment: which option explains your requirement, first or second?

Comment: Do you need header row only or header row + empty row ?

Comment: Please,email me hameed7475@gmail.com

Comment: I can't comment here in explain,so thats why

Comment: May be you can use https://gist.github.com/ to share the code and then i can look into it.